# Azure cosmos Db Criteria query with subdocuments - java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, criteria

I'm new to azure cosmos db. i'm trying to read items from container in my spring boot application. i'm using cosmos template with criteria. lets say i have a document like this

```
{
    "stop_id": 70021,
    "stop_name": "CALTRAIN - 22ND ST STATION",
    "stop_lat": 37.757692,
    "stop_lon": -122.392318,
    "zone_id": 3329,
    "trip": [{
        "trip_id": "RTD8997283",
        "arrival_time": "05:40:00",
        "departure_time": "05:40:00",
        "stop_id": 70021,
        "stop_sequence": 1
    }, {
        "trip_id": "RTD8997283",
        "arrival_time": "05:52:00",
        "departure_time": "05:52:00",
        "stop_id": 70021,
        "stop_sequence": 2
    }]
}
```

if i want to fetch based on stop id, i can add criteria for stop id like this

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.getInstance(CriteriaType.IS_EQUAL, "stop_id", Collections.singletonList("70021"), Part.IgnoreCaseType.ALWAYS);
CosmosQuery cosmosQuery = new CosmosQuery(criteria).with(Sort.unsorted());
Iterable<StopInfo> items = cosmosTemplate.find(cosmosQuery, StopInfo.class, "myContainer");
```

But if i want to add criteria for trip id, how can i do it?

Comment: Could you pls explain what 'add criteria for trip id' mean? Add a property for 'trip'? Add an item in 'trip' array? Or anything else?

Comment: @Tiny-wa i meant adding a filter condition while reading data using cosmosTemplate, as i've already mentioned for stop id like this `Criteria.getInstance(CriteriaType.IS_EQUAL, "stop_id", Collections.singletonList("70021"), Part.IgnoreCaseType.ALWAYS);`
Similar to this i want to do for trip id

Comment: Follow the [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.query.criteria.getinstance?view=azure-java-stable), I think you may try this ' Criteria.getInstance(CriteriaType.IS_EQUAL, "trip.trip_id", Collections.singletonList("RTD8997283"), Part.IgnoreCaseType.ALWAYS);
' .

Comment: @Sundarrajan Excuse me? Have you got any progress?

Comment: @Tiny-wa tried that already but didnt work. moved from SQL API to MONGODB API in azure cosmos. this is much better i guess

Answer (score 0):

This way you can search from array in cosmos using criteria

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("trip_id","RTD8997283");
Criteria criteria = Criteria.getInstance(CriteriaType.ARRAY_CONTAINS, "trip", Collections.singletonList(map), Part.IgnoreCaseType.ALWAYS);
CosmosQuery cosmosQuery = new CosmosQuery(criteria).with(Sort.unsorted());
Iterable<StopInfo> items = cosmosTemplate.find(cosmosQuery, StopInfo.class, "myContainer");
```